# Transpile mct to cx without QuantumCircuit

Tags: qiskit, transpile

to convert my circuit **mct** instructions to **cx** I transpiled a Qiskit circuit, but I want to do it without a circuit, because I want more qubits than Qiskit can handle (50 or more).

This is because I'm training a BPN neural net to be a cx gate acting on bloch coordinates. It inputs are control and target qubits  bloch coordinates before cx, and outputs the same but after cx.

So how can I change mct instructions to cx, transpiling or what?

Comment: Hi, Can I ask what you mean when you say that your circuit has more qubits than qiskit can handle? Is your transpilation just taking a long time to run? Or is there some sort of hardcoded limit on circuit size that you are encountering?  Thanks :)

Comment: Yes a 20 qubit transpilation to RX RY RZ X CX H gates  takes a lot, so 50 is eternity. So for training the BPN  there is no problem, because I can use circuit's with few qubits. but If want to use a set of BPN's for big database search, I need a circuit with lot's of qubit's that Qiskit can not give me. That's why I need a method to convert mct to cx.

Comment: I see. If you don't mind installing the `pytket-qiskit` package then you could convert your qiskit `QuantumCircuit` to a pytket `Circuit` and try to compile/transpile it with TKET istead. No gaurentee that this would work better but could be worth a try. See -> https://cqcl.github.io/pytket/manual/manual_circuit.html#importing-exporting-circuits . If this interests you I can provide details on how to do this.

Comment: Also worth noting that for many compiler/transpiler passes the gate count or depth of the circuit can be a bigger contribution to the runtime than the number of qubits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think your problem is related with `QuantumCircuit`, but with synthesis of such as big MCT. By default, the amount of resulting gates grows very quickly (it looks exponentially), as more qubits are involved

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import transpile

cxs = []
for controlled in (range(3,20)):
    target = 0
    control = list(range(target+1,controlled))
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num+len(control))
    qc.mcx(control, target)
    result = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['rx','ry','rz','cx'])
    cxs.append(result.count_ops()['cx'])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(cxs)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot qubits vs cxs in the result. Hockey stick graph]

With 20 qubits, the default synthesis results in 800K CXs gates.

However, this default synthesis method uses no ancillas. In [the mct documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.mct.html), should would notice that there are several "modes". The `v-chain` mode is the most efficient in terms of the result, but uses the biggest amount of ancillas. The amount of resulting cnots grows linearly with the amount of controlled qubits:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import transpile

cxs = []
for controlled in (range(3,20)):
    target = 0
    control = list(range(target+1,controlled))
    ancilla = list(range(len(control)+1, 2*len(control)-1))
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num+len(control)+len(ancilla))
    qc.mcx(control, target, ancilla, mode='v-chain')  # <-
    result = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['rx','ry','rz','cx'])
    cxs.append(result.count_ops()['cx'])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(cxs)
plt.show()
```

[image: linear groth]

So, you can create a quantum circuit that considers these ancillas, it would look something like this:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import transpile

target = 0 # <- qubit 0 as a target 
control = list(range(target+1,60)) # <- controlled qubits
ancilla = list(range(len(control)+1, 2*len(control)-1)) # <- ancilla qubits
print('target', target)
print('control', control)
print('ancilla', ancilla)

qc = QuantumCircuit(num)
qc = QuantumCircuit(num+len(control)+len(ancilla))
qc.mcx(control, target, ancilla, mode='v-chain')
result = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['rx','ry','rz','cx'])

print(result.count_ops())
```

```
target 0
control [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
ancilla [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116]
OrderedDict([('rz', 463), ('cx', 348), ('ry', 230), ('rx', 1)])
```

Comment: As I said with cirq.decompose_multi_controlled_x with free qubits = num controls -2  gives many many much less gates than qiskit. I tested both.

Comment: same for mct than for mcx?

Comment: I don't know exactly the difference between both, but i did it for  mct.

Comment: For example in Qiskit 9 controls translated to cx and rx ry rz are 3067 gates, while in cirq are 212 gates. More qubits, bigger difference between both

Comment: Here is a .py that generates a function with the gates for a number of controls as parameter with the cirq method. https://github.com/jesusmontera/varios/blob/5825596cb6f2f9d069f548eddb91ef3826d20b48/makemctfunctions.py#L1

Comment: I extended the answer with MCX. Have a look.

Comment: thanks gives 65% gates for num = 500 (9000 vs 14000) but, what is num?, I mean whose are controls and who is the target?

Comment: I will rewrite it the full answer in terms of the circuit, I think it is easier to understand the wiring in that way. @egretta-thula make me notice that mct and mcx are aliases.

Comment: done, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Fist use **cirq.decompose_multi_controlled_x** with num free qubits = num controls -2 and then **transpile each ccx**( always 2) with qiskit (15 instructions each). That works fast for lot's of qubits and give much less instrucions than qiskit transpile